# Default value if null or if value doesn't exist in the table Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, model, default

I have a product model like this below:

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
...
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default='Mercedes')
...
```

When I am posting a product without the brand field it works and sets the product with brand default value, but when I add a brand field like this `brand: "",` or send a value which doesn't exist inside Brand table like this: `brand: "abc123",` it shows me informations:
`This field may not be null.` and `Invalid pk \"abc123\" - object does not exist.`. I still want to set the default value in this situations, so if the value is null or does not exist I want to use the `default='Mercedes'`. How can I do this?

Comment: Are u using serializers? `This field may not be null` errors come from where?

Answer (score 1):

For problem 1). Set `null=True` on the `brand` field in the `Product` model. This will allow null values for that field in the db.

For problem 2). Assuming you want to create the brand instance if it doesn't exist you can use `Model.objects.get_or_create()`.

```
obj, created = Brand.objects.get_or_create(
    other_field='Foo', # optional if other fields have defaults
    another_field='Bar', # optional if other fields have defaults
    defaults={'name': 'Toyota'}, # the fallback value if object doesn't exist
)
```

`obj` is the retrieved or newly created object and `created` will tell you whether the obj existed or not.

Then use the `obj` for `brand` when you create your `Product`.

If you don't want to create an object, you can just use `get()` in a `try` `except` statement:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

try:
    brand = Brand.objects.get(name="Toyota")
    product = Product.objects.create(brand=brand)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    # handle exception
```

Comment: Thank You, but I don't want to set null when I am sending ```brand: "",```, I want to set the default value in this situation. Also when the brand doesn't exitst, I don't want to create a new one, but I want to set the default value.